# How can I monitoring all the exceptions in jvm?

Tags: java, exception, agent

in an agent I use the UncaughtExceptionHandler, but is't only can catch the unhandled exceptions (what a suprise). I would like to know about any (un)handled. What is the easyes way ( or any way) to reach it with java agents?

Comment: GIve more details with some code... so someone can solve your problem

Comment: I have an agent winth the exception handler, which works fine. I need to monitoring exeptions which are handled. I think, my code is irrelevant for this problem, because all I wrote is correct, and I have no code for what I need.

Comment: this might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4468992/how-to-monitor-exceptions-or-errors-generated-by-other-java-applications